# DataTables en Angular no termina de cargar, pero no muestra algún error por consola

Tags: angular, datatables, angular6, angular-datatables

Carga todos los datos de la consulta, pero no desaparece el texto "Processing..." y no configura la tabla como es, porque debería de crear la paginacion.

**categoria.component.html**

```html
<table datatable [dtOptions]="dtOptions" class="row-border hover">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>ID</th>
      <th>Nombre</th>
      <th>Status</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody *ngIf="categoria?.length != 0">
      <tr *ngFor="let categorias of categoria">
       <td>{{ categorias.id }}</td>
       <td>{{ categorias.nombre }}</td>
       <td>{{ categorias.status }}</td>
      </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tbody *ngIf="categoria?.length == 0">
    <tr>
      <td colspan="3" class="no-data-available">No data!</td>
    </tr>
  <tbody>
</table>
```

**categoria.component.ts**

```
this.dtOptions = {
  pagingType: 'full_numbers',
  pageLength: 10,
  serverSide: true,
  processing: true,
  ajax: (dataTablesParameters: any, callback) => {
    this._categoriaService.getCategorias().subscribe(
      result => {
        if(result.code != 200){
          console.log(result);
        }else{
          this.categoria = result.data;
        }
      },
      error => {
        console.log(error);
      }
    );
  },
  columns: [{ data: 'id' }, { data: 'nombre' }, { data: 'status' }]
};
```

Imagen del error:
[image: Processing...]

El ***Json*** que obtengo de la url es el siguiente:

```
{
  "status": "success",
  "code": 200,
  "data": [
    {
      "id": 6,
      "nombre": "jardin",
      "status": true
    },
    {
      "id": 7,
      "nombre": "ciudad",
      "status": true
    },
    {
      "id": 8,
      "nombre": "flores",
      "status": true
    },
    {
      "id": 9,
      "nombre": "fantasia",
      "status": true
    },
    {
      "id": 18,
      "nombre": "Espacio",
      "status": true
    },
    {
      "id": 23,
      "nombre": "Tela",
      "status": true
    },
    {
      "id": 24,
      "nombre": "Cultura",
      "status": true
    },
    {
      "id": 25,
      "nombre": "Pais",
      "status": true
    },
    {
      "id": 26,
      "nombre": "Hogar",
      "status": true
    },
    {
      "id": 27,
      "nombre": "Zapatos",
      "status": true
    },
    {
      "id": 28,
      "nombre": "Pantalones",
      "status": true
    },
    {
      "id": 29,
      "nombre": "Insigneas",
      "status": true
    },
    {
      "id": 30,
      "nombre": "Cuadros",
      "status": true
    },
    {
      "id": 31,
      "nombre": "Baño",
      "status": true
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Según la documentación [datatables - processing](https://datatables.net/reference/option/processing)  puedes poner como false mediante el sgte codigo.

```
"processing": false,
```

Para lo que es paginacion puedes poner esté codigo

```
"paging": true,
"lengthMenu": [ [10, 25, 50, 100, -1], [10, 25, 50, 100, "All"] ],
"pageLength": 10,
```

Suerte.